# do the trezor wallets support all crypto currencies for strorage?

Tags: trezor

I am considering buying a trezor wallet. I am wondering if this type of wallet can support all types of crypto currencies?

Answer (score 1):

See ["Which coins are currently supported?"](https://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-faq/overview.html#which-coins-are-currently-supported) on Trezor FAQ

> At this moment it is Bitcoin, Ethereum (+ all ERC-20 tokens), Ethereum Classic, ZCash, Litecoin, Namecoin, Dogecoin, Dash and Bitcoin Testnet[image]

So the conclusion is, Trezor supports most of the altcoins, but the computer software doesn't. If you can't code a software that allows Trezor to hold more altcoins, you can only use the altcoins in the list, with the name of the wallet next to it.